# I keep getting the error "uninitialized local variable '_ 'used" even though in if statements I initialize variables

Tags: c++

Here is the program I wrote to try to find the largest and smallest of 4 integers. If I do define the variables before the if statements it removes the error but gives me just the original numbers instead, completely untouched.

```
int I, II, III, IV;

printf("Enter four different integers: ");
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &I, &II, &III, &IV);

int s, l;

if (I > II)
{
    I = l;
    II = s;
}
else
{
    I = s;
    II = l;
}

if (III > s)
{
    if (l < III)
    {
        III = l;
    }
}
else
{
    III = s;
}

if (IV > s)
{
    if (l < IV)
    {
        IV = l;
    }
}
else
{
    IV = s;
}

printf("\nLargest: %d\n", l);
printf("Smallest: %d\n", s);
```

Way to replicate mistake:

```
int I;
int a = 1;

a = I;
```

Comment: Where are `s` and `l` initialized/set?

Comment: Side note: When you find yourself with sequentially named or numbered variables, you'll often find you can simplify the code with an array.

Comment: Please try to: create a minimal reproducible example; use variable names that have something to do with the purpose of the variables; and explain the overall intention of the code.

Comment: I'm sorry, the first answer said that I needed to swap the sides of the variables. I  accidentally put them on the wrong  side of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment operator copies the value in *righthand* to the variable in *lefthand*.

You have to swap lefthand and righthand operator of all of your usage of `=`.

For example, you should write `s = I;` instead of `I = s;`.

Comment: Wow, that was a silly mistake. I'll mark your answer right asap. Thank you!